# qemu network problem - guest and host can not communicate - everything else is ok

Tags: networking, qemu

I am running a Windows XP guest on a Debian host. For networking, I added a bridge and a tap on the host and use static adresses. Communication between host and guest does not work, but the guest reaches the internet. The host can ping the guest IP, but the guest cannot ping the host IP.

This is in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet manual
auto tap0
iface tap0 inet manual
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
 address 192.168.1.1
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 192.168.1.222
 pre-up ip tuntap add tap0 mode tap user rudi
 pre-up ip link set tap0 up
 bridge_ports all tap0
 bridge_stp off
 bridge_maxwait 0
 bridge_fd 0
 pre-up ip addr add 192.168.1.234/24 dev tap0
 pre-up ip link set tap0 up

post-up ip route del 192.168.1.0/24 dev tap0
post-up ip route add 192.168.1.234/32 dev tap0
post-up route add default gateway 192.168.1.222
post-down ip link del dev tap0
```

and this is the qemu command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
 -drive file=/home/user/emu.img,format=raw -m 1G -daemonize \
 -netdev tap,id=net0,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no \
 -device e1000,netdev=net0,mac=52:54:17:4a:c4:63 \
 -enable-kvm \
 -cpu host \
 -boot c
```

Comment: What is the IP address of the XP guest? Is it static or dynamic?

Comment: As mentioned above, all addresses are static:host 192.168.1.1, guest 192.168.1.234, gateway 192.168.1.222